# MongoDB read documents within transaction

Tags: mongodb, transactions

Suppose I do the following list of operations in MongoDB

- Start a session
- Start a transaction for that session
- run an `insert` command with a new document
- run a `find` command on the collection of the inserted document
- Commit the transaction
- End the session

I understand that outside of the transaction the insert done in the third step will not be visible until the transaction is committed, but what about within the transaction, will the `find` run in the fourth step see this new document or will it not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, a transactional `find` sees a document inserted in a previous transactional `insert`. You could assume the *Read your own writes* property.

---

Every time a transaction is started a new snapshot is created. Outside the transaction, the snapshot is obviously invisible: this is accomplished by using (and abusing if your transaction involves many updates) the WiredTiger cache. This cache is structured as a tree, similar to the following one<sup>1</sup>:

[image: wiredtiger cache]

where each transactional operation is represented as a new update block that could in turn be chained to another update block.

Outside operations only see non-transactional tree entries, while transactional operations see all the entries added before the snapshot is taken + the update blocks for the given transaction.

I am aware that it is a very brief explanation on how MongoDB manages transaction atomicity, but if you are interested in understanding more on this, then I suggest you to read a [report](https://github.com/marco-luzzara/mongodb-transaction-simulation/blob/main/doc/README.md) I have written. in the same repository you can find some [scenarios](https://github.com/marco-luzzara/mongodb-transaction-simulation/blob/main/test/transaction.test.js) for the most typical doubts.

---

<sup>1</sup>: image taken from Aly Cabral's presentation about [How and when to use Multi-document transactions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3x_Pf9rQGCo)

Comment: Thank you! And if you're having trouble like I am - `findOneAndUpdate` finds the value and returns its PREVIOUS value. If you want to do an `update` and a `find` you have to do them separately to see the updated value in the transaction. This had me tripped up for a few hours. I wasn't sure why my `findOneAndUpdate` kept returning the old properties. I thought the `update` wasn't happening at all or that it wasn't visible during the transaction context.

Comment: There is `returnDocument` argument which you can pass to `findOneAndUpdate` which when set to `"after"` will return value after the update